# node js and mysql issue

Tags: mysql, node.js

I created a node.js app, that deals with a mysql database and also renders a very simple index.html as a front end.

I tried to deploy it on render but after a few second of successfull connection it disconnects and crashes:
here is the relevant code:

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Middleware
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json());

// Database connection
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: *****,
  user: ****,
  password: ****
  database: "parcels",
});

db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log("Connected to database");
});
```

Comment: I prefer mysq2 to mysql as a package since it has better functionalities IMHO. Anyway without looking at the errors you receive it is impossible to answer

Comment: if you could provide a snippet of error message or some logs that will be helpful.

Comment: @kelbal         Did someone forget the need to CLOSE() the connection?  Scroll down in this url for an example, please.  
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html